# gsoap multi-threading issue (client/server)

Tags: multithreading, server, client, gsoap

I have two applications that communicate with **SOAP** requests with each other. Both interfaces use the same interface definition implemented with **gsoap**.
The server side is run with **mod_gsoap** for Apache. The client side is a **custom-written C++** program.
Running one thread on the client side and a couple of workers on the Apache side, it works without problems. When I start up more than one thread within the client, I get error messages for high loads like this:

`Error -1 fault in message exchange[no subcode] - "End of file or no input: message transfer interrupted" " or "SOAP 1.1 fault SOAP-ENV:Client[no subcode] - "Operation not permitted`.

If an error is reported, there are at least two requests that fail at the same time, so it looks like a race condition.
Each client thread creates its own instance of the Proxy. Since I compiled it with an **is-Soap** flag (-i), each thread should have its own soap struct instance that way as well.

I am a bit at a loss here. I have checked with wireshark what is going on. In a healthy case, there is the network handshake between client and server, the request is posted and the apache sends back `HTTP OK`. Then the client initiates the disconnect, handshake - done.
In broken cases, I see a physically new connection from client to the server - identified by a new port on client side -  that has not been established with a handshake. The first action is sending **FIN**,**ACK**, the server sends the `HTTP OK`, leading to the client sending a **RST** (reset).

Answer (score 0):

After more checking, it turned out that the same soap struct was indeed used by more than one thread. So the described symptoms are that of sharing a soap struct by different threads.

The bug was in creating the threads for the objects using the soap structs:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Sender>> senders;
// create sender objects and fill senders

 for (auto s : senders) {
      auto thread_s=make_shared<thread>([&]{tl->run();});
      threads.push_back(thread_s);                                     
 }
```

Using the reference in the lambda expression lead to all threads referencing the same object in the end.